# list with infinite elments

Tags: python

I need to operate on two separate **infinite list** of numbers, but could not find a way to generate, store and operate on it in python.

Can any one please suggest me a way to handle infinite Arithmetic Progession or any series and how to operate on them considering the fact the minimal use of memory and time.

Thanks every one for their suggestions in advance.

Comment: have a look at scipy or pandas

Comment: Why not just `itertools.count`?  The OP wanted an Arithmetic progression.

Comment: To store infinite list you need a really big hard drive.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are looking for a [python generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead:

```
def infinitenumbers():
    count = 0
    while True:
        yield count
        count += 1
```

The `itertools` package comes with a pre-built [`count` generator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> c = itertools.count()
>>> next(c)
0
>>> next(c)
1
>>> for i in itertools.islice(c, 5):
...     print i
...
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 3):

This is where the `iterator` comes in.  You can't have an infinite list of numbers, but you can have an infinite iterator.

```
import itertools
arithmetic_progression = itertools.count(start,step) #from the python docs
```

The docs for Python2 can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score 3):

I have another python3 solution (read SICP chapter 3.5)

```
class Stream:
def __init__(self, head, tail):
        self.head = head
        self.tail = tail
        self.memory = None
        self.isDone = False
def car(self):
        return self.head
def cdr(self):
        if self.isDone:
                return self.memory
        self.memory = self.tail()
        self.isDone = True
        return self.memory
def __getitem__(self, pullFrom):
        if pullFrom < 1 or self.memory == []:
                return []
        return [self.car()] + self.cdr()[pullFrom - 1]
def __repr__(self):
        return "[" + repr(self.car()) + " x " + repr(self.tail) + "]"
def map(self, func):
        if self.memory == []:
                return []
        return Stream(func(self.car()), lambda: Stream.map(self.cdr(), func))
def from_list(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return []
    return Stream(lst[0], lambda:
                  Stream.from_list(lst[1:]))
def filter(self, pred):
    if self.memory == []:
        return []
    elif pred(self.car()):
        return Stream(self.car(), lambda: Stream.filter(self.cdr(), pred))
    else:
        return self.cdr().filter(pred)
def sieve(self):
    return Stream(self.car(), lambda: self.cdr().filter(lambda n: n % self.car() > 0).sieve())
def foreach(self, action, pull = None):
    if pull is None:
        action(self.car())
        self.cdr().foreach(action, pull)
    elif pull <= 0:
        return
    else:
        action(self.car())
        self.cdr().foreach(action, pull-1)and run:

a = Stream(0, lambda: a.map((lambda x: x + 1)))
print(a[10])
```

which returns:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` .

But streams are lazily evaluated, so:

```
>>> a = Stream(0, lambda: a.map((lambda x: x + 1)))
>>> print(a)
```

prints:

`[0 x [...]]`

Answer (score 1):

To create an object that acts like a "mutable" infinite list, you can overload the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods in a class:

```
class infinite_list():
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.assigned_items = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.assigned_items:
            return self.assigned_items[key]
        else:
            return self.func(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key , value):
        self.assigned_items[key] = value
```

Then, you can initialize the "infinite list" with a lambda expression and modify an item in the list:

```
infinite_thing = infinite_list(lambda a: a*2)

print(infinite_thing[1]) #prints "2"
infinite_thing[1] = infinite_thing[2]
print(infinite_thing[1]) #prints "4"
```

Similarly, it is possible to create an "[infinite dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812982/975097)" that provides a default value for each missing key.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the natural way to generate an infinite series is using a generator:

```
def arith(a, d):
   while True:
     yield a
     a += d
```

This can be used like so:

```
print list(itertools.islice(arith(10, 2), 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
from hofs import *
def cons_stream(head,tail):
    return [head,tail,False,False]
def stream_cdr(strm):
    if strm[2]:
        return strm[3]
    strm[3] = strm[1]()
    strm[2] = True
    return strm[3]
def show_stream(stream, num = 10):
    if empty(stream):
        return []
    if num == 0:
        return []
    return adjoin(stream[0], show_stream(stream_cdr(stream), num - 1))
def add_streams(a , b):
    if empty(a):
        return b
    if empty(b):
        return a
    return cons_stream(a[0] + b[0] , lambda : add_streams( stream_cdr(a), stream_cdr(b)))
def stream_filter( pred , stream ):
    if empty(stream):
        return []
    if pred(stream[0]):
        return cons_stream(stream[0], lambda : stream_filter(pred, stream_cdr(stream)))
    else:
        return stream_filter( pred , stream_cdr( stream ))
def sieve(stream):
    return cons_stream(stream[0] , lambda : sieve(stream_filter(lambda x : x % stream[0] > 0 , stream_cdr(stream))))
ones = cons_stream(1, lambda : ones)
integers = cons_stream(1, lambda : add_streams(ones, integers))
primes = sieve(stream_cdr(integers))
print(show_stream(primes))
```

Copy the Python code above.
When I tried it, i got [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29] which is 10 of an infinite list of primes.

Comment: Oh, also in hofs.py enter:

Comment: 'def empty(data):
    return data == []

def adjoin(value,data):
    result = [value]
    result.extend(data)
    return result

def map(func, data):
    if empty(data):
        return []
    else:
        return adjoin(func(data[0]), map(func, data[1:]))

def keep(pred, data):
    if empty(data):
        return []
    elif pred(data[0]):
        return adjoin( data[0] , keep(pred, data[1:]))
    else:
        return keep(pred, data[1:])'

Answer (score 0):

You need hofs.py to be

```
def empty(data):
    return data == []

def adjoin(value,data):
    result = [value]
    result.extend(data)
    return result

def map(func, data):
    if empty(data):
        return []
    else:
        return adjoin(func(data[0]), map(func, data[1:]))

def keep(pred, data):
    if empty(data):
        return []
    elif pred(data[0]):
        return adjoin( data[0] , keep(pred, data[1:]))
    else:
        return keep(pred, data[1:])
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score -3):

I assume you want a list of infinite numbers within a range. I have a similar problem, and here is my solution:

```
c = 0
step = 0.0001 # the difference between the numbers
limit = 100 # The upper limit 
myInfList = []
while c <= limit:
    myInfList.append(c)
    c = c + step
print(myInfList)
```

Comment: Your while loop will never reach limit because you need to do `c = c + step` or `c += step` instead of just `c + step`

Comment: In what sense is this an infinite list?

Comment: Thanks @MarkDickinson, Just fixed that.

Comment: This just let you have many numbers as far as your limit and step allows. It looks like the original question is to have an AP with limit, but that requires a step @MarkDickinson